# How can I update data in a JSON file while using UptimeRobot?

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I am creating an Economy [Discord Bot](https://discord.ly/infinix) using Python and I am hosting it on [Replit](https://repl.it) and keeping it online using [UptimeRobot](https://uptimerobot.com/). Sometimes, when people use my bot's economy commands, the data is not updated in the JSON file. I have observed that this only happens when my UptimeRobot monitor brings my bot online and not when I manually run the code. Does anyone know how to work around this?

Here is the code I am using to update the JSON file:

```py
with open("data.json", "w") as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: Do you get any errors when it doesn't update the JSON file?

Comment: No, I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here might be with replit. Replit reboots your repl every once in a while, even if you have hacker plan or are using uptime robot. And sometimes the JSON file might not be saved. In this case the file reverts to its last saved state. As far as I'm aware, there is no way to work around this. The only way is using an external database like MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

I would dump your json a little differently.. PS. I have never seen this kind of thing happen so it might just be the way your json dump code is.

```py
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

So we just open the json file `data.json` or whatever your json file is called. We define it as `f` and we dump your `data` or whatever you called it into `f`... the `indent=4` just makes it more clean but you can get rid of it if you want.